# How to replace all numbers in a string with custom string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

I want to replace all the numbers in a given string with `Mat(number)`.For example the string `A*256+B*12+C*256` after conversion must look like this `A*Mat(256)+B*Mat(12)+C*Mat(256)`.**How can I perform this in python 3?**.

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please, show us your attempt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) with the following pattern:

```
import re
s = 'A*256+B*12+C*256'

re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'Mat(\1)', s)
# 'A*Mat(256)+B*Mat(12)+C*Mat(256)'
```